# Unable to create login with Windows or SQL Server authentication in SQL Server 2012 Standard

Tags: sql-server

I am getting the following error every time I am trying to create a login (windows/sql) in SQL Server:

**Query:**

USE [master]

GO

CREATE LOGIN [domain\loginname] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]

GO

**Error:**

> Msg 8143, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_send_dbmail, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 2]
> Parameter '@profile_name' was supplied multiple times.

I'm unable to figure out what could be the issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: That message has nothing to do with creating a `LOGIN`; creating a login doesn't do anything with `sp_send_dbmail`. Clearly you have a badly written trigger on your instance you need to fix. If you do not understand the t offer, then post its DDL in the question (that ugh the error is telling you the problem).

Comment: Assuming you're not calling `sp_send_dbmail` yourself, it sounds like somebody wrote a trigger to capture this event, and this trigger was constructed poorly. Check under database/server triggers.

Comment: USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [domain\loginname] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]
GO this is what i am running. I agree with you, it is possibly a trigger. where should I look for the trigger.

Comment: `where should I look for the trigger` ... In SSMS, you'd look under [Yourdatabase] -> Programmability -> Database triggers. Probably for this one, you'd be looking in the master database. Triggers can also exist under individual tables.

Comment: This is more likely to be a server trigger, not a database one, @ADyson .

Comment: Put stuff like that in the question, @iftekharrayhan , not the comments.

Comment: @Larnu using stackoverflow for the first time. Checked all the databases there are no triggers under database triggers.

Comment: `Server Objects -> Triggers` for server triggers. Please [edit] to add the definition of the trigger

Comment: Thank you all. Found the trigger and took out the duplicate parameter and everything worked. thanks again

Comment: *"Checked all the databases there are no triggers under database triggers."* Because it won't be a database one, as I mentioned, it'll be a server trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks like is you are using a variable, and that one is never SET again.
I will suggest you use that way to create your Login accounts.
If you need to create multiple accounts, you can use a cursor or a while statement that loop against a temp table where you saved the domain accounts that you want to create.

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
go  
use master
go 

declare @domainuser SYSNAME
DECLARE @sqlCMD nvarchar(2000)
SET @domainuser = 'YourDomain\UserName'

SET @sqlCMD = N'CREATE LOGIN ['+ @domainuser +'] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = [master];'

--PRINT @sqlCMD
EXEC (@sqlCMD)
GO
```